# Javascript filtering string and boolean array object and duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, boolean

Lets say, I have object array like below,

```
data = [{ name: 'A', place: 'chennai', placeChecked:true}
{ name: 'A', place: 'America', placeChecked:true}
{ name: 'A', place: 'America', placeChecked:true}
{ name: 'A', place: 'Delhi', placeChecked:false}
{ name: 'B', place: 'Delhi', placeChecked:false}
{ name: 'B', place: 'Delhi', placeChecked:false}
{ name: 'B', place: 'Canada', placeChecked:true}]
```

I want to filter column and wants the output like below

```
"name":{"A","B"}
"place":{"Chennai","America","Delhi","Canada"}
"placeChecked":{true,true,false,true}
```

Using Object.keys I am able to fetch the keys

```
Object.keys(data[0]).forEach((ele: string) => this.map.set(ele, new Set()));
```

But unable to assign the boolean values for the corresponding keys.

```
data.forEach(keys => {
  for (const key in keys) {
    this.map.get(key).add(keys[key]);
   }
})
```

Comment: `"name":{"A","B"}` or `"name":{"A","A","B","B"}` ?

Comment: Why are there duplicates in `placeChecked`?

Comment: Duplicate values coming from server side. so need to process this data. name should be like  "name" : {"A","B"}

Comment: @Sapthika so here `placechecked` values will be multiples rather than only `4 values`(as shown in your expected output), unique values will be only `name` and `place`, right?

Comment: @gorak placeChecked values should be 4 values only as shown in expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `reduce`. I hope this will lead you to the further direction.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'A', place: 'chennai', placeChecked:true},{ name: 'A', place: 'America', placeChecked:true},{ name: 'A', place: 'America', placeChecked:true},{ name: 'A', place: 'Delhi', placeChecked:false},{ name: 'B', place: 'Delhi', placeChecked:false},{ name: 'B', place: 'Delhi', placeChecked:false},{ name: 'B', place: 'Canada', placeChecked:true}];

var result = data.reduce((acc,elem)=>{
  Object.entries(elem).forEach(([k,v])=>{
    acc[k] = [...(acc[k] || []),v];
    acc[k] = [...new Set(acc[k])];
  });
  return acc;
},{});

result.placeChecked = result.place.map(k=>data.find(p=>p.place==k).placeChecked);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Sapthika I have edited the answer, have a look, and let me know.

Comment: is there any other way without hardcoding result.placeChecked and result.place?